# How to find the age of the oldest item in Redis?

Tags: redis

Memcached provides **max_age** but couldn't find something similar for Redis. Is it that Redis doesn't support this kind of metadata?

Answer (score 5):

Redis doesn't save the age of the keys. If you set a fixed TTL on all keys, you can sample a few keys and by viewing their TTL you can know their age (since all objects have the same TTL). This way you can statistically estimate the oldest key.

Comment: It will give oldest key but not age of the oldest key. My use-case was to flush cache everyday and I was planning to use max_age to do sanity check i.e. nothing from previous day is left in the cache. Probably, I can live with EXPIREAT command i.e. clear key at the day boundary or set TTL = day boundary - current time.

Comment: @Amit it will give you an estimated age of the oldest key. The age is always `$GLOBAL_TTL - $OBJECT_TTL`, i.e. an object with 6400 seconds TTL was created 80000 seconds ago. 

Anyway, sounds like you're just looking for LRU and expiration, which redis does without saving the age.

Comment: Redis doesn't have global ttl. However, setting day_boundary (which we can assume global ttl) - current time as ttl works, just that doing it in application is slow (python code).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no kind of max_age functionality in Redis, except if you set a TTL for each key.

Comment: How would setting TTL for each key will give age of the oldest key?

Comment: You can theoretically loop on every key and check the TTL of each of them. Pretty tough, I admit..